# Gradle war customization - folder name

Tags: java, gradle, war

I need to include additional folder inside my war file.
I found following documentation page: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html 
And followed the example from there (only relevant part):

```
    war {
       webInf { from 'src/additionalWebInf' } // adds a file-set to the WEB-INF dir.
    }
```

It correctly moves the content of the src/additionalWebInf folder, I need however to put the content in a folder inside webInf, not directly inside webInf. 
current situation:

```
app.war/WEB-INF/file1
app.war/WEB-INF/file2
app.war/WEB-INF/fileN
```

desired situation:

```
app.war/WEB-INF/myCustomFolder/file1
app.war/WEB-INF/myCustomFolder/file2
app.war/WEB-INF/myCustomFolder/fileN
```

How do I move files into a custom (new) folder inside webInf using gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to add another level to `additionalWebInf` such that the files are at `src/additionalWebInf/myCustomFolder/fileN`.

To answer your question: Reading the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:webInf%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) the `webInf` closure configures a [CopySpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html)

So you can do

```
war {
   webInf { 
      from 'src/additionalWebInf' 
      into 'myCustomFolder'
   }
}
```

Or

```
war {
   webInf { 
      with copySpec({
         from 'src/additionalWebInf1' 
         into 'myCustomFolder1'
      })
      with copySpec({
         from 'src/additionalWebInf2' 
         into 'myCustomFolder2'
      })
   }
}
```